Can you have a diastereomer with one chiral center? If yes, give me example
If we say yes, how? Because if the compound have 1 chiral carbon, thus if it is S and another compound is R thus is mirror imagested

Yes, it's possible.
Diastereomers are stereoisomers which are not mirror images of each other. This also includes geometrical isomers like cis trans isomers. Hence a molecule may have any number of chiral centres (even zero) and it might still have a diastereomer.
(See attached image)

Won’t this be E/Z rather than cis-trans?

It is both. You can say the first one is cis as the two H atoms are closer and the second is trans as the H atoms are far apart. Alternatively you can say they are E/Z isomers as well.

Shouldn't cis and trans only be used if we have the same "set" of compounds/elements. As in if either carbon had Br and H, it would be cis and trans. E/Z happens when you start prioritising with molar mass.

True , at least one atom attached to each carbon must be same for cis trans isomerism.CHCl=CHCl will show cis trans isomerism. However both atoms attached may not be same that is CHBr=CHCl will also show cis trans isomerism. But CClBr=CHF will not show cis trans isomerism
